# New tabs in webkit

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

How open new tab in browser(webkit). Via javascript, html or api webkit - it does not matter. and that it was not a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Browsers do not expose any kind of page-accessible API to control browser tabs, this is to ensure that only the user is in control.

Note that you can create new browser windows, and that the browser *might* open those new windows in a new tab (if the user has selected that option) but you otherwise have no control over it.

It isn't a WebKit property: WebKit is only concerned with what happens *within* the tab, not the tabs themselves (unlike Firefox/Gecko which uses the same rendering engine for the UI and pages).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programmatically open a new tab in webkit. The only option available to you at present is to open a new window. The user has to configure the behavior of their particular webkit-based browser as to whether opening a new window starts a new tab or a completely separate window.

Comment: Thanks for response. Setup in safari open new window in new tab. But how setup chrome?

Comment: Chrome can't do it by default. You'll have to install a Chrome Extension such as One Window: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/papnlnnbddhckngcblfljaelgceffobn